# Not able to insert data in file using append mode in c++

Tags: c++, file

my code is this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
fstream file;
file.open("abc.txt",ios::app);
file<<"hello";
file.close();
return 0;
}
```

The above code is creating an empty file.

Please can anyone point it out where i'm going wrong.

Comment: I think you need to declare in your `open()` call that your file is for output and append (`ios::out | ios::app`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open your file, in addition to specifying append (`ios::app`), you must also specify that you want to output to the file (`ios::out`). You combine them with a bitwise or (`|`) since they represent single bit flags.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("abc.txt",ios::app | ios::out);
    file << "hello";
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but that is the case when you are not sure whether file exists or not. If it doesn't exist then it will create one.

Comment: here if the file abc.txt exist , then why can't i open it in append mode directly and write data to it

Comment: When a file stream is opened, it is required that you declare whether you intend to read to it, write to it, or both. `ios:app | ios::out` is still append mode because `ios::out` only specifies that you intend to write to the file. `ios::out` will create a new file if it is not present or use the existing one if it is present.